# How to adjust Logistic Regression classification threshold value in Scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to adjust threshold values on logistic regression classification.

If i can not adjust it, I wonder if the threshold is always fixed at 0.5.

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716241/controlling-the-threshold-in-logistic-regression-in-scikit-learn