# how to calculate accuracy, precision, recall, f1_score for k fold cross validation or fix this code?

Tags: python, cross-validation, metrics, multiclass-classification, precision-recall

I have an imbalanced dataset containing 4-class classification,i have built MultinomialNB and used k fold cross validation with 10 folds, i wanted to calculate accuracy, precision, recall, f1_score

so i used the following to do so

```
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
       'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score),
       'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score), 
       'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score)}                                                   
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)                                     
model = MultinomialNB()                                                                  
scores = cross_validate(model, X_train_tfidf, y, scoring=scoring, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1) 
print(scores)
```

but as an output all the arrays are NaN

```
'test_accuracy': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),
'test_precision': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), 
'test_recall': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), 
'test_f1_score': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])}
```

i also used

```
scoring = {'accuracy' : 'accuracy', 
       'precision' : 'precision',
       'recall' : 'recall'
      }
```

but still the same result

So is there another why to calculate accuracy, precision, recall, f1_score, for k fold cross validation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute precision,recall and f1 score of an imbalanced dataset for K fold cross validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598301/how-to-compute-precision-recall-and-f1-score-of-an-imbalanced-dataset-for-k-fold)